# Visual Studio - This database cannot be imported

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to insert an entry into a table in visual studio, but after I run my code and then try to view the table I get this error message,

This database cannot be imported. It is either an unsupported SQL server version or an unsupported database compatibility.

Here is the code that is attempting to insert,

```
private void doneButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string userName = userNameTextBox.Text,             
        password = passwordTextBox.Text,
        question = questionMenu.Text,
        answer = answerTextBox.Text;
        int key = EncryptionClass.generateKey();

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyData.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    connection.Open();

    String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.Account(UserName, UserPassword, UserKey) " +    
           "VALUES (\'" + userName + "\', \'" + EncryptionClass.encrypt(password, key) + "\', " + key + ");";

    Console.WriteLine("string " + sqlQuery);
    // INSERT INTO dbo.Account(UserName, UserPassword, UserKey) VALUES ('victoramaro', 'obvmhkT1', 19);

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection)) {
        try {
            var res = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } catch (SqlException ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
        connection.Close();
}
```

And the App.config,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Assign6.Properties.Settings.MyDataConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyData.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />   
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

In the properties of MyData.mdf Build Action is set to Content, Copy to Output Directory is set to Copy if newer.

In the properties of MyDataDataSet.xsd Build Action is set to None, Copy to Output Directory is set to Do not copy.

**EDIT**

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\MyData.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

connection.Open();


String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.Account(UserName, UserPassword, UserKey) " +     //create insert query to insert user data into Account table
                        "VALUES (\'" + userName + "\', \'" + EncryptionClass.encrypt(password, key) + "\', " + key + ");";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection)) {
        try {
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();



            string selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM Account";

            SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);
            SqlDataReader sqlReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();             //execute the query 

            while (sqlReader.Read()) {                                         //while reader has data
                string outString = string.Empty;
                for (int k = 0; k < sqlReader.FieldCount; k++) {                //go throught the field count
                    outString += String.Format("{0, -8}", sqlReader[k]);        //add item to string
                }
                Console.WriteLine(outString);
            }

        }
        catch (SqlException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: How did you create/obtain `MyData.mdf`?

Comment: Project > Add New Item > Service-based Database

Comment: Other advice: always use a `using` block with `SqlConnection` instances. Also, you should just reference the connection string in your `app.config`, don't hardcode it into your `.cs` files.

Comment: What does your main look like?

Comment: It's a winform, so the main has all of three lines in it, that were generated auto.

Comment: if you are using windows form app why are you using `Console.Writeline`?

Comment: I'm just using it for testing purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in here

```
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyData.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

change to

```
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\MyData.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

or add a method/function that uses the `SqlConnentionStringBuilder` like this

```
        public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        connectionString.DataSource = "(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB";
        connectionString.AttachDBFilename = "|DataDirectory|\\MyData.mdf";
        connectionString.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        string connectString = connectionString.ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectString);
        return connection;
    }
```

and then call the method like this

```
SqlConnection connection = GetConnection()
```

and when you hit the database you should have a try catch finally like this

```
try
        {
            connection.Open();
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string selectStatement =
                "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TableName') FROM TableName";
            SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);
            int vendorID = Convert.ToInt32(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar());
            return vendorID;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: @kevin Note, if you just pull the connection string from `app.config`, you won't have to escape \

Comment: So this gets rid of the error message I was getting, but when I try to view the table contents in the server explorer it's empty.

Comment: I am going to need a bit more information how are you displaying the table

Comment: Okay, I updated my code to show what I am currently trying. So it seems like when it gets to the `ExecuteNonQuery`, it is inserting the data. I then run a Select command right after it and the data I entered is shown in the console, the data is persistent after multiple runs of the program. But when I go into the Sever Explorer to view Table Data nothing is loaded there.

Comment: It's better to use the three layers  the  UI, BLL and DAL from ado.net

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that.

Comment: UI stands for User Interface (your console app class where the main)
BLL for Business Logic Layer  ( a class that gets and sets the objects )
DAL for Data Access Layer (a class that "talks" with the database such as select insert delete update etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the properties of your local database in the server explorer section and check for the connection string property, like this -  `"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp2\WindowsFormsApp2\CarDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True"`

Copy it and past it in the connection string of your program.cs